# What's the best version of Ubuntu for a Dell Inspiron 1150

Tags: unity, dell, inspiron

I've attempted to install 12.10, but I can get a proper Unity desktop or launch button, etc.  I've tried various recommended fixes unsuccessfully, so I updated to 13.04 in the hope that it might fix any known bugs - without success. I'm stumped. I don't have the expertise or the time to work through this diagnostically. I just want a fix.

Should I settle for an earlier version? If so, which?

Answer (score 3):

According to Google, the Dell Inspiron 1150 has 256MB of RAM memory. You don't have enough RAM memory on your laptop to run Ubuntu (which requires at least 768MB RAM) or Xubuntu (which requires at least 512MB RAM), but you can run the lightweight Lubuntu (which requires only 128MB RAM) on your laptop.

<sub>**Tip:** If you can upgrade your RAM memory to 512MB, then you can install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which is supported by updates until April, 2017, on your laptop. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS requires only 384MB RAM.</sub>

Comment: This particular machine has 748MB, which is probably a bit light.  I don't think that's causing the problem though.